# how would I return my data in my rear node? im trying to create a dequeue rear function

Tags: java, linked-list, queue, deque

So as you can see this is my deque. I dont think im correctly using my rear pointer. Cause right now its only returning the value of the front of the list. I just need help trying to figure out how to return the value of the rear. its removing it correctly but
[its returning the wrong value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUko4.png). Sorry i tried to keep it as compact as I possibly could. But i wanted to ensure it was runable

```
public class LinkedDeque <T> implements DequeInterface<T>
{
    protected LLNode<T> front;     // reference to the front of this queue
    protected LLNode<T> rear;      // reference to the rear of this queue
    protected int numElements = 0; // number of elements in this queue


  @Override
    public T dequeueRear ()throws QueueUnderflowException
    {


        if (isEmpty())
            throw new QueueUnderflowException("Dequeue attempted on empty queue.");

        LLNode<T> lastNode = front;
        LLNode<T> previoustolast = null;

            while(lastNode.getLink()!= null)
            {
                previoustolast = lastNode;
                lastNode= lastNode.getLink();

            }
            previoustolast.setLink(null);

            return lastNode.getInfo();


    }
 @Override
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (front == null);

    }
 public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        LLNode<T> temp = front;
        while(temp!=null) {
            result += temp.getInfo()+" ";
            temp = temp.getLink();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
public class LLNode<T>
{
  protected LLNode<T> link;
  protected T info;

  public LLNode(T info)
  {
    this.info = info;
    link = null;
  }

  public void setInfo(T info){
    this.info = info;
  }
  public T getInfo(){
    return info;
  }
  public void setLink(LLNode<T> link) {
    this.link = link;
  }
  public LLNode<T> getLink(){
    return link;
  }
}

public class LinkedDequeTestDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        LinkedDeque<Integer> myLinkedDeque = new LinkedDeque();

        myLinkedDeque.enqueueRear(10);
        myLinkedDeque.enqueueRear(20);
        myLinkedDeque.enqueueRear(30);
        myLinkedDeque.enqueueRear(40);
        myLinkedDeque.enqueueRear(50);
        System.out.println("Queue");
        System.out.println(myLinkedDeque);
        myLinkedDeque.dequeueRear();
        System.out.println(myLinkedDeque);
        myLinkedDeque.dequeueRear();
        System.out.println(myLinkedDeque);
        System.out.println(myLinkedDeque.dequeueRear());
    }

public interface DequeInterface<T>
{
  void enqueueFront(T element) throws QueueOverflowException;
  // Throws QueueOverflowException if this queue is full;
  // otherwise, adds element to the front of this queue.

  void enqueueRear(T element) throws QueueOverflowException;
  // Throws QueueOverflowException if this queue is full;
  // otherwise, adds element to the rear of this queue.

  T dequeueFront() throws QueueUnderflowException;
  // Throws QueueUnderflowException if this queue is empty;
  // otherwise, removes front element from this queue and returns it.

  T dequeueRear() throws QueueUnderflowException;
  // Throws QueueUnderflowException if this queue is empty;
  // otherwise, removes rear element from this queue and returns it.

  boolean isFull();
  // Returns true if this queue is full; otherwise, returns false.

  boolean isEmpty();
  // Returns true if this queue is empty; otherwise, returns false.
  
  int size();
  // Returns the number of elements in this queue.

  String toString();
}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal, runnable example which illustrates the problem.

Comment: I updated it. So when you say minimal. how would i make this minimal. is this good? The reason i opted just to post the bare necessities is so i could focus in and make my question as clear as possible. which was that something was up with the way my dequeue rear function is working. something is wrong with the way im using my rear pointer. Hope this is more helpful. i even included an image of the problem to make it even more clearer. there is an arrow pointing to show that the removal is working but the returning is not. Thank you!

Comment: `LinkedDeque ` doesn't implement the methods in `DequeInterface`, so the example is not runnable yet.

Comment: @tgdavies nvm I figured it out. You know what was happening. I was accidently calling deque rear twice in my test class. I called it once and then a second time in my print statement when I was trying to return the value. This whole time i was thinking there was something wrong with my function since it wasnt returning the value i was excepting. Sry for the confusion I knew it was something simple.